# Disable Listview item clicks if user is not premium user

Tags: android, listview, google-play, checkedtextview

I have a listview with checkedTextview items as the rows. the listview is the layout for a navigation drawer.

What I'm trying to achieve is, If they are not premium, prompt the play store dialog box and don't not allow them to alter the state of the check. If they are premium, do not show the premium dialog box, and allow them to alter the state of the check boxes.

I tried an if/else in several different places to Check if they are premium or not, but it didn't work because I was still able to click and change the state of the checkboxes.

the items in the list view are only access able/clickable to premium users. if they are not premium then when they click on a list item a google play dialog box will prompt the user to upgrade. I have tried
alot of different options like setting listvivew.setEnabled(false) and setClickable(false), and .invalidate(); amongst other things but nothings worked so far.

```
 private void addDrawerItems() {
    String[] osArray = {"Bluetooth", "Reply to Calls", "Reply to sms", "customise message"};

    mAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice, osArray);
    mDrawerList.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);
    mDrawerList.setAdapter(mAdapter);



    mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {


        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

            CheckedTextView ctv = (CheckedTextView) view;


            switch (position) {

                case 0:

                        if (ctv.isChecked()) {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Bluetooth On", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        } else {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Bluetooth OFF", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }

                    break;

                case 1:
                    if (ctv.isChecked()) {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Calls Reply On", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Calls Reply OFF", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                    break;

                case 2:
                    if (ctv.isChecked()) {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Sms Reply On", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Sms Reply OFF", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                    break;

                case 3:

                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Customised Message", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    break;
            }
        }
    });
}
```

[!What my Navigation Drawer Looks like[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/02BTm.jpg)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/02BTm.jpg)

Comment: Just add a condition in your cases before you control the check state? (if (userUsesPremiumVersion){click!}else{open dialog}  - or do you have trouble with identifying premium users?

Comment: "if they are not premium then when they click on a list item a google play dialog box will prompt the user to upgrade" - so do you need the ListView OnItemClickListener to trigger the dialog ? Then why would you want to disable it?

Comment: What I'm trying to achieve is, If they are not premium, prompt the play store dialog box and don't not allow them to alter the state of the check. If they are premium, do not show the premium dialog box, and allow them to alter the state of the check boxes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the `ListView` choice mode depending on the user privileges.

If we assume you have a global variable to indicate the user state

```
boolean mIsPremiumUser;
```

then depending on its value:

```
if (mIsPremiumUser)
{
    mDrawerList.setChoiceMode(AbsListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);
}
else
{
    mDrawerList.setChoiceMode(AbsListView.CHOICE_MODE_NONE);
}
```

This will toggle the checkable state of the list items. The `OnItemClickListener` has to be changed as follows:

```
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id)
{
    CheckedTextView ctv = (CheckedTextView) view;

    if (! mIsPremiumUser)
    {
        // code to display upgrade dialog here
        return;
    }

    switch (position)
    {
        case 0:
        // continue as before...
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much that worked perfect! Exactly what i wanted. just one problem, i start the app and mIsPremiumUser is set to false, and everything works as i want it too, but then when I click a "testing" button which used to changed mIsPremiumUser to true.  I can click on the list items, but the check box does not change it state to "ticked", and the toast messages always i.e Bluetooth is off, or "Reply to calls off"

Comment: I also had another question. for the bluetooth list item, if the user clicked the checkbox I wanted the check to toggle on or off, but if the user clicks anywhere else on that row, I wanted a little dialog box to open up to allow the user to select from a list of paired devices. I only want this effect/design for the bluetooth list item, for the other list items I want the user to click anywhere on that row to toggle the checkbox.

Comment: @Andrew Irvin - I tested with a small activity with a button to toggle the user state just like you seem to be doing. Maybe it's best if you post some of your code to [this chat room](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107355/discussion-between-0x0nosugar-and-andrew-irwin) and I'll take a look at it. About the other problem: I have a feeling somehow that the special behavior for the bluetooth row is best achieved by using a custom adapter with a custom ViewGroup as list row. This problem is certainly  deserving its own question. Not least because someone else may have a more elegant solution.

Comment: Hi im back today working on my app, but when tried to open that chat room that we opened it wasnt there and I could get the code. would you be able to reopen the chat room or send me on the code to andrewirwinds@gmail.com

Comment: @AndrewIrwin - I've asked the SO people to reopen the room. I hope they will but I don't know how long this may take.

Comment: Thanks very much for your reply !  I had a mini heart attack this morning when I saw the chat had disappeared! Because I really need that code. Do you still have it or know it ? Any chance you could send it onto andrewirwinds@gmail.com

Comment: I have the problem that after the user is set to premium, the check boxes are clickable but always return a false value i.e "bluetooth off"

Comment: I have noticed that once the user has been set to premium, the app has to be restarted for the checkboxes to work correctly again

Comment: @AndrewIrwin - just found the txt file in the waste paper basket (you're really lucky it still was in there!) and tried to send mail, but (short:) something did not work. As I've asked to re-open the old chat, I'd like to wait a little while before creating a new one.